# Why can Selenium not access these dynamically loaded elements?

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

There should be seven elements whose class is “top_search”. However, an empty list is printed with the following despite using implicitly_wait:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get('http://www.egglandsbest.com/where-to-buy/') 
print driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="top_search"]')
```

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: Ultimately I'm trying to get a search box (this failed as well). For testing, I'm trying to get any dynamically loaded element on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to an iframe:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("http://www.egglandsbest.com/where-to-buy/")
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("destini"))
print driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="top_search"]')
```

I just had a quick look at the source to pull that,there are numerous iframes so you will have to sift through and see which ones you need.

Comment: I’ve never heard of or had to ‘switch to frame’ when dealing with AJAX. This works, but interestingly not with maximize_window for some reason.